# Lazy loading setup in Angular project

Tags: angular

I would like to have a lazy loaded module for my articles components. Basically I can call these components from 2 different modules and in both of them the routes will look like this:

-if I want to fetch all the articles I will go to **module1//articles**
-if I want to fetch a single article I will go to **module1/:articleId**

Same goes for the other module.

Is there a way I could do this with lazy loading since there is no universal string with which I can access this module like **/articles** and then fetch all of them with **/articles/all** and single article with **/articles/:articleId**? If that was the case it would not be a problem to implement lazy loading. It would look like this:

module 1:

```
 {
    path: 'articles',
    loadChildren: () => import('./articles/articles.module').then(m => m.ArticlesModule)
},
```

articles-routing.module:

```
 {
    path: 'all',
    component: AllArticlesComponent
},
{
    path: ':articleId',
    component: SingleArticleComponent
```

But unfortunately the routes setup must stay as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matcher in that case and match the route with custom logic. not sure it's best way but i have solved it in similar way in past.

Check the following example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-matcher?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts